# Node child_process trying to use /usr/bin/zsh and failing as it does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, zsh

Since recently, many npm commands have been failing for me with an error message similar to this one:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn /usr/bin/zsh
npm ERR! file /usr/bin/zsh
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/zsh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! myProj@0.1.0 preinstall: `npm run myCommand`
npm ERR! spawn /usr/bin/zsh ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myProj@0.1.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

So far I have found out, that this error is probably caused by `/usr/bin/zsh` not existing. zsh is located under `/bin/zsh` on my system.

The content of the script causing this error is:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('npm -v', (err, stdout) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (parseFloat(stdout) < 5) {
    // NOTE: This can happen if you have a dependency which lists an old version of npm in its own dependencies.
    throw new Error(`[ERROR] You need npm version @>=5 but you have ${stdout}`);
  }
});
```

the verbose stack contains:

```
17 verbose stack spawn /usr/bin/zsh ENOENT
17 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
17 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
17 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

So most likely child_process is trying to call /usr/bin/zsh. But I have no Idea why and how to fix this. Any Ideas?

This problem seems to be similar to this one: [Trying to run concurrently (npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395339/trying-to-run-concurrently-npm-err-code-elifecycle-npm-err)

Complete reinstall of node, npm and nvm did not help. The error also occurs when using yarn.

Another debugging problem:

I cannot find `internal/child_process.js` or `internal/process/next_tick.js` anywhere.

Edit: I have found out, that this error ocurrs regardless of the script that is being run.

If i run a script `npm run x` which is defined in package.json as `"x"="npm run y"`. That will fail. But if I run `npm run y` directly, it works.

Comment: Not the correct solution but you could try symlinking the zsh binary to `/usr/bin/zsh`

Comment: Did `/usr/bin/zsh` exist when the code was installed? The installer may have modified  the scripts to use a hard-coded path. The code *should* be relying on path lookup, or installing its own dependencies in a know location, though.

Comment: afaik it never existed. And symlinking is not only possible in that location by disabling some osx security measures. Which I think I'll do now.

Comment: Unfortunately even after disabling the osx security thing I still get "ln: /usr/bin/zsh: Read-only file system"

Comment: From the Node docs: *"Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell, buffering any generated output."* and about the shell option: *"Default: '/bin/sh' on Unix"*. So see what `/bin/sh` points to.

Comment: /bin/sh is an existing executable of sh

Comment: Which version of Node are you using?

Comment: I have tried several: 8.17, 13.9, 12. I reinstalled nvm, npm and node. Still the same issue. Must be some sort of misconfiguration I guess?

Comment: Rereading the question, it looks like more related to `npm` than node itself? If you create your own script that uses `exec`, does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an npm bug. Running the script on node works without a problem

Answer (score 0):

I have now overridden two OSX security measures to hacky-fix this issue:

1. disable SIP (system integrity protocol) by rebooting into recovery (holding CMD + R), opening Utilities -> Terminal, and running `csrutil disable`
2. removing the write protection of /usr/bin by running:

   sudo mount -uw /
   killall Finder

   3. Creating the symlink `ln -s /usr/bin/zsh /bin/zsh`

Now the error is gone. But its cause and a proper fix is still unknown